# Is there any way to deploy UI via wcf?

Tags: library, c#, .net

I'm new to C# and .NET.

I have some session hosts and because of some problem, if I want to change some content in the UI I have to update it one by one per each session host. I don't want to do this and hence I'm looking for the way to provide the service without deploying it to any client.

I heard that there is a DLL library pointing to a website. So I thought that if such library really exists, then if I can just update the contents in the web by deploying the pointer library to session hosts.

So I looked for the way to implement the idea for some hours, but failed. So what I want to ask is :

1. Is there a library just pointing the real contents in a web? if so, where can I find the information about it?
2. If there is no such library, is there any other way to implement it? I heard about WCF and thought WCF might be another answer.